# getting min and max height of a tree in one traversal of Binary tree in Java?

Tags: java, tree, height, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I have two methods to get min and max height of a binary tree in Java. But I am doing two traversals through the root two times. each is `log n in Big(O)`. Is there a way to compute both min and max in same traversal and return as an array with two indices corresponding to min and max.

Here are my methods

```
public static int minHeight(Node root){
            if (root==null) return -1;
            return 1+Math.min(minHeight(root.left), minHeight(root.right));
        }

public static int height(Node root){
            if (root==null) return -1;
            return 1+Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right));

        }

class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int data;

        public Node(int c){
            this(c, null, null);
        }
        public Node(int c,Node left, Node right) {
            this.data = c;
            this.left=left;
            this.right=right;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Each traversal is actually `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes. You may be confusing your complexity analysis with that of *finding* a node in a *binary search tree* (a special case of a binary tree), which is amortized `O(log n)`. Your code calls `height()` (or `minHeight()`) once for every node in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute the heights in one pass, and track the min and max as you go. Your confusion lies in the fact that your functions return a single value, but really you need to determine a pair of values. So, you can pass in, say, an object that has a field for both that you can store the results in, and return your results through that instead of through the return value of the function:

```
class MinMax {
    public int min;
    public int max;
}

void computeMinMaxHeight (Node root, MinMax minmax) {
    // update the fields of minmax accordingly
}
```

A convenient way to initialize the fields of `MinMax` might be:

```
class MinMax {
    public int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

Or add some flag that indicates that it is uninitialized, so the values are filled in correctly for the first item.

Edit: You could also return an `int[2]` array as Changgeng suggests; it just depends on what you find more semantically appropriate. Personally, I'd opt for something like `MinMax` (Java doesn't really have a standard class for representing value ranges), plus passing the output parameter to the function saves you on object allocations, if that is significant.

Comment: I can always have min and max fields in my Node and update them as and when new nodes are added. but thats not my point. I want to have calculate in one traversal both min and max if possible

Comment: Storing the min and max in the nodes is not what I suggested. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion of Big(O) is incorrect. In your implementation you need to access every node in the tree, so the time complexity would be `O(n)`.

Level order tree traversal could give the answer in one time, but you need two queues to do that correctly.

```
public int[] findMinMax(Node node) {
    Queue<Node> currentLevel = new LinkedList<Node>();
    Queue<Node> nextLevel = new LinkedList<Node>();

    currentLevel.offer(node);
    int currentHeight = 1;

    int[] result = new int[]{Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};
    while (!currentLevel.isEmpty() || !nextLevel.isEmpty()) {

        if (currentLevel.isEmpty()) {
            currentHeight += 1;
            Queue<Node> tmp = nextLevel;
            nextLevel = currentLevel;
            currentLevel = tmp;
        }

        node = currentLevel.poll();
        if (node.left != null) {
            nextLevel.offer(node.left);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            nextLevel.offer(node.right);
        }
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            result[0] = Math.min(result[0], currentHeight);
        }
    }

    result[1] = currentHeight;

    return result;


}
```

Saying that, it's really not worth it normally. Recursive solution is much easier to write and to understand.

Comment: no, its not O(n) but log(n), each time you do max on recursive call, you go to one branch of tree. you dont go through all the branch

Comment: @user1988876 You would have to go through both branches to evaluate both parameters to `Math.max()` (in order to determine which one was the maximum, you have to compute both), the complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree (you have to visit them all).

Answer (score 0):

you could always have two properties on each node showing the min and max height of the node.

```
  this.max = Math.max(this.left.max,this.right.max) + 1 ; 
  this.min = Math.min(this.left.min,this.right.min) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

public class MinMax {

```
public void printMinMaxNumbers(int[] nums){
    int min = nums[0];
    int max = nums[1];
    for(int n:nums){
        if(n < min){
            min = n;
        } else if(n > max){
            max = n;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Minimum Number: "+min);
    System.out.println("Maximum Number: "+max);
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    int num[] = {5,34,78,21,79,12,97,23};
    MinMax tmn = new MinMax();
    tmn.printMinMaxNumbers(num);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide some explanation also?